# Writing JavaScript code using PHP echo statements (for leaflet map points)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to create map points in Leaflet, which uses JavaScript to write points, for example:

```
L.marker([39.0865039, -9.2636987], {icon: tree3}).addTo(map)
 .bindPopup('<a class="speciallink">Olive Tree</a>')
 .openPopup();
```

In MySQL I have the coords stored, and then I tried to make the following code:

```
    <?php
     $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arv_especie");
     $rowArv=mysql_fetch_array($res);
     $idPointVarzea=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map_point_varzea");
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($idPointVarzea)) {
       echo "L.marker([" . $row["coordHori"] . ", " . $row["coordVerti"] . "], {icon: tree" . $row["ARV_id"] . "}).addTo(map)
       .bindPopup($('<a class='speciallink'>" . $rowArv["ARV_Especie"] . "</a>').click(function() {
       document.getElementById('DivShow" . $row["ARV_id"] . "').click();
       })[0])
       .openPopup();";
     }
?>
```

this code is inserted in a `<script type="text/javascript">`, not in a external file.

I'm using this process so that in the back office I can CRUD the map points.

I have searched and found out that PHP echo statements don't work (or at least the way I am approaching it) in JavaScript.

is there a better way to write JavaScript code using PHP?

Comment: Why not use ajax to make the call to your `php` file. Have the php return the coordinates so that you can handle them within the process of using ajax....

Comment: i will try it, thank you for your time

Comment: **Please** stop using the deprecated mysql_* API. Use mysqli_* or PDO. Then you can avoid the security concerns associated with this library and use parameterised queries to properly protect yourself against SQL injection attacks. Although the query shown here is not vulnerable, anything you write that relies on variables to complete the query will be wide open to hacking. Also mysql_ is removed entirely in PHP7 as well, so whenever you upgrade to this version your code will cease to work at all.

Comment: i knew mysql_ was not as good as mysqli_, i'm in my 2nd year of programming course, in my first year was all C# and ASP.net, this year was PHP, and my teacher teach us with mysqli_, but i dunno why i liked mysql_ better, but i think you are right, time to upgrade, if everything works after making the changes i will warn you, thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better way to write javaScript code using PHP?

Yeah. You don't.

While writing JS on-the-fly from PHP is cool, it is also very prone to errors and [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)/SQL injection attacks.

A cleaner way to do the same is to use PHP to write the *value of a variable* in JS, then let JS do all the work. Your code will be better split, will be easier to debug, and you'll have a single point where your variables have to be escaped.

Something like:

```
<script>

<?php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arv_especie");
$rowArv=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$idPointVarzea=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map_point_varzea");

// This will hold a data structure mimicking a GeoJSON FeatureCollection
// See http://geojson.org/
$featureCollection = [ "type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>[] ];

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($idPointVarzea)) {

    $feature = [
        "geometry"=>[
            "type"=> "Point",
            "coordinates"=> [ $row["coordVerti"] , $row["coordHori"] ]
        ],
        "properties"=> [
            "species"=>$rowArv["ARV_Especie"],
            "id"=>$row["ARV_id"]
        ]
    ];

    $featureCollection["features"][] = $feature;
}
?>

// PHP shall echo() $featureCollection as JSON, which JS will parse nicely.
// From here on, the JS variable "dataInGeoJsonFormat" holds all the needed data
var dataInGeoJsonFormat = <?php echo json_encode($featureCollection); ?>

var markers = L.geoJSON(dataInGeoJsonFormat, {
    onEachFeature: function(feat, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('ID: ' + feat.properties.id + '<br>Species:' + feat.properties.species)
    }
}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

My PHP is quite rusty, but you should get the idea. If you use this pattern, you'll be able to debug your javascript and have a look at your data. Using well-known formats such as GeoJSON means that you can enjoy features and tutorials from elsewhere.

By having a *single* point in the code where the data is encoded into JSON (and by using PHP's built-in `json_encode`), you'll save yourself a lot of headaches and potential mistakes. You can set breakpoints in your JS code and inspect the value of that variable, before any of your JS code runs.

This is not the only pattern available. However, this will prevent you from making mistakes.

Comment: $featureCollection["features"].push($feature); <- this line is making my map disappear, and of course, when i remove it the map doesnt show any point, any idea why is this happening? what i understood from the great example is that $featureCollection is collecting data to form an array, isn't something to do with array_push? idk i'm kinda newbie, i'm doing this for a school work

Comment: I said that my PHP is rusty, so yeah, that should be something like `array_push($featureCollection["features"], $feature)`. Or even `$featureCollection["features"][] = $feature`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a javascript layer to request geojson from your php/crud server rather than attempting to embed the geojson in the php constructed response. You will have better separation of concerns and, if you are interested, there are several php frameworks and libraries capable of producing geojson or facilitating a crud system.

EX: [Doctrine2-Spatial](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial) for [Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/) support mysql geometries.

Disclosure: I work on D2-Spatial and Leaflet.Draw

Comment: i already solved this problem with the exact explanation you just did! i had to go more and more in depth with leaflet and geojson documentation do understand how to do this, i marked your answer as the correct one